# ShowInTaskBar set to false, window still visible in taskbar

Tags: wpf

If I set ShowInTaskbar to false, the window is still visible in the taskbar (Windows 10). Which is not what I want.

The xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="mycontrol.TextureProperties"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:foo"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         Title="Textures Dialog"
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
         Height="300"   Width="300" ResizeMode="NoResize" ShowInTaskbar="False" >
<Grid Width="300" Height="300">
    <Label Content="Textures Display here" />
</Grid>
</Window>
```

And the code behind:

```
public partial class TextureProperties : Window
{
    public TextureProperties()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

}
```

and how I'm instantiating it:

```
textures = new TextureProperties();
textures.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual;
Debug.Assert(textures.ShowInTaskbar == false);
textures.Owner = this;
textures.Show();
```

Other:

1. .NET 4.6.2
2. Running on windows 10

I have tried:

1. calling textures.ShowDialog(), which also does not work
2. searching for similar questions here on stackoverflow. I found one which was kind of related. They wanted to show the window on the taskbar, not hide it like I want. Never-the-less I tried the answer (setting the owner property), which didn't help me.
3. Just a note, that my assert that `ShowInTaskbar` is false, passes. The assert does not fire at runtime.
4. All the different WindowsStyle options, which still doesn't help.

[Edit]

After further testing, I found that after the call to the windows `Show()` method, it sets ShowInTaskbar to true again. *Not nice WPF!!*

```
textures.Show();
Debug.Assert(textures.ShowInTaskbar == false);
```

In the code above, the assert fails at runtime. So why is that getting set behind my back?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `#if DEBUG //...// #endif` instead of `Debug.Assert(..)`?

And also check your debug configuration - maybe it fails because of Release one :)